# Evaluate $\int\sin^m(x)\cdot \cos^n(x) \;dx$. Can I solve this way?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, solution-verification, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluate $\int\sin^m(x)\cdot \cos^n(x)dx.$

I am doing some pre-reading for lecture and I have seen that my lecturer has used a long method. I have used a different method.

$=\int\sin^m(x)\cdot \cos^n(x) \;dx \\=\int\sin^m(x)\cdot \cos^{2k+1}(x) \;dx\\=\int\sin^m(x)\cdot (1-\sin^2x)^k \cdot \cos(x) \;dx\\=\int(\sin^m(x)-\sin^{2m}(x))\cos(x) \;dx$

Let $u=\sin(x)$

Then, $du=\cos(x)\;dx$

$\int(u^m-u^{2m}\,du)=\frac{\sin^{m+1}(x)}{m+1}-\frac{\sin^{2m+1}(x)}{2m+1}+c.$

Could you check if this method is correct?

Comment: How did $\sin^m (x) (1-\sin^2 x)^k$ become $\sin^m(x)-\sin^{2m}(x)$?

Comment: You need to clearly define the exponents - m,n,k and their relationships.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the problems;

At your second equal sign, you assume $n$ is odd.  This method won't work if both $m$ and $n$ are even.

At your fourth equal sign, you've made an algebra error as pointed out by @player3236 in the comments above.  So your last integral should be

$$\int u^m(1-u^2)^k \; du.$$

If $k$ is large, then you have some multiplication to do.